# Error Could not get JDBC Connection when java web tries connect to mariadb galera cluster

Tags: mysql, spring, mariadb, mybatis

I have a java webapp with spring mvc, mybatis, jndi and tomcat

Additionally, On Tomcat context.xml, I defined:

```
<Resource auth="Container" 
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
maxIdle="100" maxTotal="100" 
name="jdbc/dbExample" 
password="dbpass" 
type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
url="jdbc:mariadb:sequential://192.1.1.12,192.1.1.13,192.1.1.14:3306/dbExample" 
username="dbuser"/>
```

Also, in pom file I have the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.6</version>
</dependency>
```

The database is mariadb galera cluster multimaster.

Then when I test the web app I got the following error:

Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'] with root cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

What can I do?

Comment: You can put the diver jar inside tomcat lib folder and try again.

Comment: I tried that but it's not working. It shows the same message. I tested the application by debugging with STS Ide

Comment: Here is an excerpt from the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/) :
 "Please note that the driver class provided by MariaDB Connector/J is not com.mysql.jdbc.Driver but org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver!" There may be some duplicates like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44875544/1261766).

Comment: Yes, you're right. I changed on Tomcat context.xml file by allocating the  driverClassName to org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver and it started to work.